# Event not found csh

Tags: csh

I have this very simple csh script.

```
#!/bin/csh
        echo "Hello World!"
        echo "How are you today?"
```

But I am getting the error `": Event not found.`

What is wrong?

Comment: Modify the 1st line into `#!/bin/csh -f` and try again. It may be related to your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

csh uses the `!` character for history substitution.  So in the sequence `!"`, the `"` is not treated as the closing quotation mark for the string; rather, the shell searches for something in your command history starting with `"`, just as typing `!foo` at the command line repeats the most recent command starting with `foo`.

At least for the original csh, this substitution is always done, even in single-quoted strings (so changing double quotes to single quotes won't necessarily help).

The only way to escape a `!` character is with a `\` backslash:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
echo "Hello World\!"
echo "How are you today?"
```

(On *some* systems, I find that using single quotes rather than double quotes does avoid the error. I think that's because on those systems `/bin/csh` is a symlink to `/bin/tcsh`, which works a bit differently. You shouldn't depend on that if you want your script to be portable.)

Note that I've also added a `-f` option to the `#!` line. This prevents the shell from executing your `$HOME/.cshrc` on startup, and it's generally a good idea for csh scripts. It makes them run a bit faster, and it prevents accidental dependence on your own `.cshrc`, which could be a problem when others run your script.

And in any question about csh scripting, I am legally obligated [*] to post this link:

http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

[*] *I am not actually legally obligated to post this link.*

Comment: TL;DR: "What is wrong?"  "csh."   +1 to both question and answer.